# Cover negative values in a group first by backward checking then by forward checking

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

First time posting on this website, so I am not sure if I am posting in the Snowflake forum or not.  I am trying to figure out the following in Snowflake.  My company is implementing a new analytics platform, which uses Snowflake.  I am new to my environment so I am not sure I can use a stored procedure in what I am doing.  If possible, I would like to figure the following out using a WITH statement and several CTEs.

My problem is: I have a set of rows where I need to "cover" negative values.  First by looking at earlier positive values, then by looking at later positive values.

For example, in the below table, I want to cover the -149 from Period 2, first with the 141 in Period 0 and next from the 74 in Period 4.  Then I want to cover the -61 in Period 8 from the 400 in Period 6.  The Expected column is what I expect when I am finished.

| MATERIAL | PLANT | PERIOD_NUM | PERIOD_ATP | Expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Material A | 1710 | 0 | 141 | 0 |
| Material A | 1710 | 2 | -149 | 0 |
| Material A | 1710 | 4 | 74 | 66 |
| Material A | 1710 | 6 | 400 | 339 |
| Material A | 1710 | 8 | -61 | 0 |

Another example below:  I want to cover the -61 from Period 2 with the 141 in Period 0.  Then I want to cover the -149 first from the 74 in period 4 and then from the remainder available in Period 0.

| MATERIAL | PLANT | PERIOD_NUM | PERIOD_ATP | Expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Material A | 1710 | 0 | 141 | 5 |
| Material A | 1710 | 2 | -61 | 0 |
| Material A | 1710 | 4 | 74 | 0 |
| Material A | 1710 | 6 | -149 | 0 |
| Material A | 1710 | 8 | 400 | 400 |

The following is the closest I have gotten.  I believe this may work for the second example if I reran the W_DESCENDING_GROUPING and W_DESCENDING_ATP a second time off of the first results of those CTEs.  And maybe that is what I have to do.  But, I thought I would ask if anyone has a more elegant solution.

But, here is an example I don't think will work at all with the below:

| MATERIAL | PLANT | PERIOD_NUM | PERIOD_ATP | Expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Material A | 1710 | 0 | 141 | 0 |
| Material A | 1710 | 2 | -20 | 0 |
| Material A | 1710 | 4 | -61 | 0 |
| Material A | 1710 | 6 | -149 | 0 |
| Material A | 1710 | 8 | 400 | 311 |

```
WITH W_ATP_PERIOD_CALC AS
(
    SELECT 
         'MAT 1'        AS Material
        ,'1710'         AS Plant
        ,0              AS Period_Num
        ,141            AS Period_ATP
    UNION
    SELECT 
         'MAT 1'        AS Material
        ,'1710'         AS Plant
        ,2              AS Period_Num
        ,-61            AS Period_ATP
    UNION
    SELECT 
         'MAT 1'        AS Material
        ,'1710'         AS Plant
        ,4              AS Period_Num
        ,74             AS Period_ATP
    UNION
    SELECT 
         'MAT 1'        AS Material
        ,'1710'         AS Plant
        ,6              AS Period_Num
        ,-149           AS Period_ATP
    UNION
    SELECT 
         'MAT 1'        AS Material
        ,'1710'         AS Plant
        ,8              AS Period_Num
        ,400            AS Period_ATP

),    W_DESC_GROUPING AS
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Period_Num
        ,Period_ATP
        -- ,SUM(Period_ATP)
        ,SUM
         (
             CASE 
             WHEN Period_ATP < 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END
         )
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
             ORDER BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Period_Num DESC
         )                                  AS Desc_Grouping
    FROM
        W_ATP_PERIOD_CALC
)
,    W_DESCENDING_ATP AS
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Period_Num
        ,Period_ATP
        ,Desc_Grouping
        ,SUM(Period_ATP)
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Desc_Grouping
             ORDER BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Desc_Grouping
                ,Period_Num DESC
         )                                  AS Running_Sum_DESC
        ,RANK()
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Desc_Grouping
             ORDER BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Desc_Grouping
                ,Period_Num DESC
         )                                  AS Desc_Rank
        ,IFF
         (
              Running_Sum_DESC <= 0
              AND
              Desc_Rank = 1
             ,0
             ,LEAST(Period_ATP, Running_Sum_DESC)
         )                                  AS Descending_ATP
    FROM
        W_DESC_GROUPING
)
,    W_ASC_GROUPING AS
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Period_Num
        ,Period_ATP
        ,Desc_Grouping
        ,Desc_Rank
        ,Descending_ATP
        ,SUM
         (
             CASE 
             WHEN Descending_ATP < 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END
         )
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
             ORDER BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Period_Num
         )                                  AS Asc_Grouping
    FROM
        W_DESCENDING_ATP
)
,    W_ASCENDING_ATP AS
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Period_Num
        ,Period_ATP
        ,Desc_Grouping
        ,Desc_Rank
        ,Descending_ATP
        ,Asc_Grouping
        ,SUM(Descending_ATP)
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Asc_Grouping
             ORDER BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Asc_Grouping
                ,Period_Num
         )                                  AS Running_Sum_ASC
        ,IFF
         (
              Running_Sum_ASC <= 0
             ,0
             ,LEAST(Descending_ATP, Running_Sum_ASC)
         )                                  AS Ascending_ATP
        ,RANK()
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Asc_Grouping
             ORDER BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Asc_Grouping
                ,Period_Num DESC
         )                                  AS Asc_Rank
        ,IFF
         (
              Running_Sum_ASC <= 0
              AND
              Asc_Rank = 1
             ,0
             ,LEAST(Descending_ATP, Running_Sum_ASC)
         )                                  AS Ascending_ATP
    FROM
        W_ASC_GROUPING
)
SELECT *
FROM W_ASCENDING_ATP
ORDER BY Period_Num
;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text (formatted appropriately), then people can copy it if they want to try out a solution

Comment: Thank your for you pointer.  I tried to copy the excel chart as text and it wanted to do an image.  So, I thought that was the way.  Also, the W_ATP_PERIOD_CALC is where I reproduce one example (that can easily be changed), so I wasn't too worried about it.

Comment: I guess enter posts when you aren't finished:

Comment: Control-Enter also:

Comment: Alt-enter also.  Sorry.  Don't know how I was able to do paragraphs before.  I just tried to add tables and it didn't work.  It didn;t do line breaks.  And I don't have the table option.

Comment: Information about how to format text as tables can be found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: Thank you NickW.  I found a tool that converted it quickly for me.

Comment: I'm not clear on how to reconcile the description of the rules/math with the expected output column. For example in the second table, why is the first row for expected "5"?

Comment: I wish I got emails when there was a post on this.  I just saw your post.  For the -61 amount I can get it from the 141 in the first row.  That leaves 80 in the first row.  For the -149 in the 4th row, I can get 74 from the third row which leaves me still needing 75.  Since the first row still has 80, I can get the 75 from it.  That leaves 5.

Answer (score 0):

Well after 12+ hours and many starts and restarts, I believe I finally have it:

```
--  To Remember:  Only processes material / plant combinations with postitive total ATP, so need to join negative at the end.
--                Can pull ATP_CALC_BASE_DATA to get the negative scenarios.

--    Only process Positive Total_ATP through this logic. Negative Total_ATP means all periods should have a zero.
WITH W_ATP_PERIOD_CALC AS
--  Base data to work with
(
    SELECT
         'MAT 1'                                        AS Material
        ,'1710'                                         AS Plant
        ,0                                              AS Period_Num
        ,141                                            AS Period_ATP
    UNION
    SELECT
         'MAT 1'                                        AS Material
        ,'1710'                                         AS Plant
        ,2                                              AS Period_Num
        ,5                                              AS Period_ATP
    UNION
    SELECT
         'MAT 1'                                        AS Material
        ,'1710'                                         AS Plant
        ,4                                              AS Period_Num
        ,-16                                            AS Period_ATP
    UNION
    SELECT
         'MAT 1'                                        AS Material
        ,'1710'                                         AS Plant
        ,6                                              AS Period_Num
        ,-14                                            AS Period_ATP
    UNION
    SELECT
         'MAT 1'                                        AS Material
        ,'1710'                                         AS Plant
        ,8                                              AS Period_Num
        ,400                                            AS Period_ATP
)
,    W_TOTAL_ATP AS
--  Get total ATP for each material / plant combo
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,SUM(Period_ATP)                                AS Total_ATP
        ,SUM
         (
             IFF(Period_ATP < 0, Period_ATP, 0) 
         )                                              AS Total_Neg_ATP
    FROM
        W_ATP_PERIOD_CALC
    GROUP BY
         Material
        ,Plant
)
,    W_RANKING AS
--  Rank periods for use in prioritizing below
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Period_Num
        ,RANK()
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
             ORDER BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Period_Num
         )                                              AS Period_Rank
    FROM
        W_ATP_PERIOD_CALC
    GROUP BY
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Period_Num
)
,    ATP_CALC_BASE_DATA AS
--  Get new base data with the Total ATP and rankings
(
    SELECT
         APC.Material
        ,APC.Plant
        ,APC.Period_Num
        ,APC.Period_ATP
        ,TA.Total_ATP
        ,TA.Total_Neg_ATP
        ,WR.Period_Rank
    FROM
        W_ATP_PERIOD_CALC APC
        INNER JOIN W_TOTAL_ATP TA
            ON APC.Material = TA.Material AND
                APC.Plant = TA.Plant
        INNER JOIN W_RANKING WR
            ON APC.Material = WR.Material AND
                APC.Plant = WR.Plant AND
                APC.Period_Num = WR.Period_Num
)
,     W_NEG_PERIODS AS
--  Pull the periods with a negative ATP
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Period_Num
        ,Period_ATP
        ,Total_ATP
        ,Total_Neg_ATP
        ,Period_Rank
    FROM
        ATP_CALC_BASE_DATA
    WHERE
        Period_ATP < 0
        AND
        Total_ATP > 0
)
,     W_POS_PERIODS AS
--  Pull the periods with a positive ATP
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Period_Num
        ,Period_ATP
        ,Total_ATP
        ,Total_Neg_ATP
        ,Period_Rank
    FROM
        ATP_CALC_BASE_DATA
    WHERE
        Period_ATP > 0
        AND
        Total_ATP > 0
)
,    W_NEG_POS_JOIN AS
--  Cartesian join the negative and positive periods together for prioritization
--  Pos and Neg Period Ranks are used to calculate the distance from the negative period to the postive period
--      This aids in prioritizing.
(
    SELECT
         POS.Material
        ,POS.Plant
        ,POS.Total_ATP
        ,POS.Total_Neg_ATP
        ,NEG.Period_Num                                AS Neg_Period_Num
        ,NEG.Period_ATP                                AS Neg_Period_ATP
        ,NEG.Period_Rank                               AS Neg_Period_Rank
        ,POS.Period_Num                                AS Pos_Period_Num
        ,POS.Period_ATP                                AS Pos_Period_ATP
        ,POS.Period_Rank                               AS Pos_Period_Rank
        ,POS.Period_Rank - NEG.Period_Rank             AS Dist_and_Direction
    FROM
        W_POS_PERIODS POS
        JOIN W_NEG_PERIODS NEG
            ON POS.Material = NEG.Material AND
                POS.Plant = NEG.Plant
)
,    W_PRIORITIZE AS
--  Earlier negatives are the first to consume positive values.  
--  So, priority is first by the order of the negative values then by the distance and direction of the positive value
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Total_ATP
        ,Total_Neg_ATP
        ,Neg_Period_Num
        ,Neg_Period_ATP
        ,Neg_Period_Rank
        ,Pos_Period_Num
        ,Pos_Period_ATP
        ,CASE
         WHEN Dist_and_Direction > 0
             THEN -20 - Dist_and_Direction                                        --    First look backward (negative), then forward. So, make the forward less than the backward
         ELSE Dist_and_Direction
         END                                            AS New_Dist_and_Direction
        ,RANK()
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
             ORDER BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Neg_Period_Rank ASC
                ,New_Dist_and_Direction DESC
         )                                              AS Priority
    FROM
        W_NEG_POS_JOIN
)
,    W_PREPARE_RUNNING_SUM AS
--  With the W_PRIORITIZE, we have the negative ATP and positive ATP in different columns.
--  Use the positive ATP and pull in the negative ATP values (which will show in the positive ATP column)
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Neg_Period_Num
        ,Pos_Period_Num
        ,Pos_Period_ATP
        ,Priority
    FROM
        W_PRIORITIZE
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Neg_Period_Num
        ,Neg_Period_Num
        ,Neg_Period_ATP
        ,0                                              AS Priority
    FROM
        W_PRIORITIZE
)
,    W_RUNNING_SUM AS
--  Get the running sum for each negative ATP group (Neg_Period_Num) by Priority
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Neg_Period_Num
        ,Pos_Period_Num
        ,Pos_Period_ATP
        ,Priority
        ,SUM(Pos_Period_ATP)
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Neg_Period_Num
             ORDER BY
                 Material   
                ,Plant
                ,Neg_Period_Num
                ,Priority
         )                                              AS Running_Sum
    FROM
        W_PREPARE_RUNNING_SUM
)
,    W_RUNNING_SUM_CLEANUP AS
--  Each group can pull from the same positive amount, thus possibly causing duplicate pulls 
--      This will be cleaned up later.
--  For each row where a negative quantity was consumed, calculate how much was consumed (Reduced_Amt)
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Neg_Period_Num
        ,Pos_Period_Num
        ,Pos_Period_ATP
        ,Priority
        ,Running_Sum
        ,CASE
         WHEN 
             Pos_Period_ATP > Running_Sum
             AND 
             Running_Sum > 0
             THEN Pos_Period_ATP - Running_Sum
         WHEN 
             Pos_Period_ATP > Running_Sum
             AND 
             Running_Sum < 0
             THEN Pos_Period_ATP
         WHEN 
             Pos_Period_ATP < Running_Sum
             THEN 0
         ELSE
             NULL
         END                                            AS Reduced_Amt
    FROM
        W_RUNNING_SUM
)
,    W_CALCULATED_ATP AS
--  Calculate the ATP as the orignal period ATP (Pos_Period_ATP) amount minus the Reduced_Amt
--  As mentioned above, this can result in a positive ATP getting drawn from too much, therefore
--      the need for the final fix below.
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Pos_Period_Num                                 AS Period_Num
        ,Pos_Period_ATP
        ,CASE
         WHEN Pos_Period_ATP < 0 THEN 0
         WHEN Pos_Period_ATP > 0 THEN
             Pos_Period_ATP -
             SUM(Reduced_Amt)
         END                                            AS Calculated_ATP
    FROM
        W_RUNNING_SUM_CLEANUP
    WHERE
        Pos_Period_Num IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,Pos_Period_Num
        ,Pos_Period_ATP
)
,    W_ATP_DESC_MAX_PERIOD AS
--    The final numbers are correct most of the time but there are exceptions. 
--    There should be no negative ATP values at this point but with the exceptions there are.
--    Identify the maximum period number with the negative ATP to run Descending ATP against.
--    Not running against the whole data set because there could be a large positive later that
--    will confuse the logic.
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,MAX(Period_Num)                                AS Max_Neg_Period_Num
    FROM
        W_CALCULATED_ATP
    WHERE
        Calculated_ATP < 0
        AND
        Period_Num <> 0
    GROUP BY 
         Material
        ,Plant
)
,    W_CALCULATED_ATP_DESC AS
--    The finall number are correct most of the time but there are exceptions. 
--    Run through the ATP values Desc to cleanup what we can descending 
--        then run through them ascending (next CTE)
(
    SELECT
         ATP.Material
        ,ATP.Plant
        ,Period_Num
        ,Calculated_ATP
        ,SUM(Calculated_ATP)
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 ATP.Material   
                ,ATP.Plant
             ORDER BY
                 ATP.Material   
                ,ATP.Plant
                ,Period_Num DESC
         )                                              AS Desc_Running_Sum
        ,CASE
         WHEN 
             Desc_Running_Sum < 0 
             THEN 0
         WHEN 
             Desc_Running_Sum > 0 
             AND
             Calculated_ATP > Desc_Running_Sum
             THEN Desc_Running_Sum
         WHEN 
             Desc_Running_Sum > 0 
             AND
             Calculated_ATP <= Desc_Running_Sum
             THEN Calculated_ATP
         ELSE
             0
         END                                            AS Desc_ATP
    FROM
        W_CALCULATED_ATP ATP
        LEFT JOIN W_ATP_DESC_MAX_PERIOD MP
            ON ATP.Material = MP.Material AND
                ATP.Plant = MP.Plant
    WHERE
        Period_Num <= IFNULL(Max_Neg_Period_Num, Period_Num)
)
,    W_DESC_JOIN AS
--    Joining the original calculated ATP results with the updates to get the descending results.
(
    SELECT
         First_ATP.Material
        ,First_ATP.Plant
        ,First_ATP.Period_Num
        ,CASE
         WHEN Desc_ATP IS NULL THEN First_ATP.Calculated_ATP
         ELSE Desc_ATP
         END                                            AS New_Desc_ATP  
    FROM
        W_CALCULATED_ATP First_ATP
        LEFT JOIN W_CALCULATED_ATP_DESC Desc_ATP
            ON First_ATP.Material = Desc_ATP.Material AND
                First_ATP.Plant = Desc_ATP.Plant AND
                First_ATP.Period_Num = Desc_ATP.Period_Num
)
,    W_ATP_ASC_MIN_PERIOD AS
--    The final numbers are correct most of the time but there are exceptions. 
--    There should be no negative ATP values at this point but with the exceptions there are.
--    Identify the minimum period number with the negative ATP to run Ascending ATP against.
--    Not running against the whole data set because there could be a large positive earlier that
--    will confuse the logic.
(
    SELECT
         Material
        ,Plant
        ,MIN(Period_Num)                                AS Min_Neg_Period_Num
    FROM
        W_DESC_JOIN
    WHERE
        New_Desc_ATP < 0
    GROUP BY 
         Material
        ,Plant
)
,    W_CALCULATED_ATP_ASC AS
--    The finall number are correct most of the time but there are exceptions. 
--    Run through the ATP values Desc to cleanup what we can descending 
--        then run through them ascending (next CTE)
(
    SELECT
         ATP.Material
        ,ATP.Plant
        ,Period_Num
        ,New_Desc_ATP
        ,SUM(New_Desc_ATP)
         OVER 
         (
             PARTITION BY
                 ATP.Material   
                ,ATP.Plant
             ORDER BY
                 ATP.Material   
                ,ATP.Plant
                ,Period_Num
         )                                              AS Asc_Running_Sum
        ,CASE
         WHEN 
             Asc_Running_Sum < 0 
             THEN 0
         WHEN 
             Asc_Running_Sum > 0 
             AND
             New_Desc_ATP > Asc_Running_Sum
             THEN Asc_Running_Sum
         WHEN 
             Asc_Running_Sum > 0 
             AND
             New_Desc_ATP <= Asc_Running_Sum
             THEN New_Desc_ATP
         ELSE
             0
         END                                            AS Asc_ATP
    FROM
        W_DESC_JOIN ATP
        LEFT JOIN W_ATP_ASC_MIN_PERIOD MP
            ON ATP.Material = MP.Material AND
                ATP.Plant = MP.Plant
    WHERE
        Period_Num >= Min_Neg_Period_Num
)
,    W_FINAL_ATP AS
--    It is possible the exception can be complex enough to require an ascending ATP
--        but haven't been able to recreate an instance for it. 
--    Joining the original calculated ATP results with the updates to get a final result.
(
    SELECT
         First_ATP.Material
        ,First_ATP.Plant
        ,First_ATP.Period_Num
        ,CASE
         WHEN Asc_ATP IS NULL THEN First_ATP.New_Desc_ATP
         ELSE Asc_ATP
         END                                            AS Final_ATP  
    FROM
        W_DESC_JOIN First_ATP
        LEFT JOIN W_CALCULATED_ATP_ASC Asc_ATP
            ON First_ATP.Material = Asc_ATP.Material AND
                First_ATP.Plant = Asc_ATP.Plant AND
                First_ATP.Period_Num = Asc_ATP.Period_Num
)
SELECT *
FROM W_FINAL_ATP
ORDER BY Period_Num
```